New naturalisation law for people with Einbuergerungszusicherung
New naturalisation law in Germany should come into force in late June 2024. I have received Einbuergerungszusicherung, i.e. a request to renounce other citizenships, which will not be needed under new law. Is it likely that they will just give citizenship once this requirement is eliminated by the new law, or will I have to apply again in order to keep existing citizenship?

You should ask the authority that issued the Einbuergerungszusicherung, for they will be the ones who will get the first copies of the administration implementation instructions on how to deal with such situations.

You should ask the authority that issued the Einbürgerungszusicherung (Naturalization assurance), for they will be the ones who will get the first copies of the administration implementation instructions on how to deal with such situations.

Is it likely that they will just give citizenship once this requirement is eliminated by the new law, or will I have to apply again in order to keep existing citizenship?

The, unofficial, advice being given is to make an appointment after the new law comes into effect. (see below)
Since the main purpose of the Einbürgerungszusicherung is to insure you (and your home country) that you will be naturalised after the renouncement of your present citizenship (avoiding permanent statelessness), it will no longer serve that purpose starting 2024-06-26.
So even if the Einbürgerungszusicherung has expired, a renewal is no longer required.
The conditions of the relevant law on the day of naturalization (not the date of the application) is what must be fulfilled, so no new application must be made.


Current update from 02.04.2024
The new Naturalization Act 2024 was published in the Federal Law Gazette on 26.03.2024!
This means it will come into force on 26.06.2024!
What does this mean for you if you have already been granted naturalization and would like dual citizenship?

Make an appointment at your local naturalization office after 26.06.2024
Exchange the naturalization assurance for the naturalization certificate
Obtaining dual citizenship



Sources:

Naturalization assurance - What you need to know!

unofficial site



